# In Apache HttpClient, how do I know whether 2 requests use same connection?

Tags: httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

The thing is, I want to do some test about keep-alive of http, so I need to know during requests, is the connection reused or a new one.

Now the only way I can do is to browse all debug logs, to find things like connection established, expired, discarded ....

My question is, if there is a more efficient way? And if browsing logs is the right way, what keywords should I pay attention to?